# check that given file is present on this path or not in Android Filesystem?

Tags: android, filesystems

How can we check the given file is present in Android Filesystem or not without using File inputstream.because I only want to check the existence of the file on the given path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File myFile = new File("/path/to/file");
if (myFile.isFile()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: myFile.exists() is redunant to isFile

Comment: @Monu I don't understand the question. If you want to search for a particular file in a directory, you'll have to use something like `File.listFiles()` on the directory you want to search.

Comment: @Graham I just want to know that why should not I use myFile.exists()  with myfile.isFile()?

Comment: @Monu `isFile()` returns true only if the file exists AND it is a file (not a directory) so the check for `isExists()` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a file using `openFileOutput` method then this works

```
File mFile = new File(getBaseContext().getFilesDir(),FileName);
if (mFile.exists() )
{
   //File is Exits.

}
else
{
//File is not Exits.
}
```

hope this helps